# Masonry multiple times

Tags: jquery-masonry

The jquery masonry script is really cool. But I was curious if anyone knew of a way to multiply it. I'd like to have two containers on the same page using it. Each container in different places.

For my purposes I want to stack one container on top of another. Each with different content.

Bonus points if you can tell me how to use jquery to load more items at the bottom of each container with a load more button. :)

Answer (score 0):

1) You have 2 containers and 2 different names for the container
2) There is a plugin infinityscroll with the masonry plugin